# How do I animate spinning arm with spinning end

Tags: modeling, animation

I have a model that looks like this.
[image: model]

I want to animate it such that the arm with the blade swings around but at the same time the blade should rotate around when it reaches the middle like.
[image: rotated model]

I'm not entirely sure how to set something like this up.

Comment: The arm is clear, but which way do you want the blade to rotate?

Comment: The blade rotates slightly counter clockwise about the Z axis. If it did not then it would intersect with the brown part with the side instead of the pointy end.

Comment: Like this? http://i.stack.imgur.com/YV9mA.gif

Comment: Ya like that how do I set that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the **origin** of the arm at the point where you want it to rotate (note that I added a cylinder object as axis, that will be used later).

[image]

Select the blade, then <kbd>shift</kbd> select the arm, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to parent the blade to the arm.
This will make it move and  rotate with the arm.

[image]

Select the blade only and add a **Copy Rotation constraint** to it. On the Target object I selected the cylinder on which the arm spins, but it could be the main object as well or an emtpy.

[image]

The blade now follows the movement of the arm but the rotation on the Z axis determined by the cylinder object.

[image]